# How to avoid returning null from a catch block?

Tags: grails, codenarc

I've got a rather simple Grails controller action which binds the parameters to a domain instance and passes that to a service which handles the persistence.

```
def finishBooking() {
    Booking booking = new Booking(params)
    try {
        booking = bookingService.saveBooking(booking)
    } catch (ReservationException e) {
        log.error("Error saving booking", e)
        flash.message = "Couldn't save the reservation."
        render(view: "index", model: [booking: booking])
        return
    }
    if (booking.hasErrors()) {
        flash.message = "Reservation failed. Check the required fields."
        render(view: "index", model: [booking: booking])
    } else {
        [booking: booking]
    }
}
```

According to [codenarc](http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/), the return statement in the catch block is a bad practice. How else would you implement the error handling?

Comment: You would not need the `return` in catch. You are rendering a view already.

Comment: How about place all code to try block and remove return from catch?

Comment: @Mr.Cat Did not mean to step on your toes... You have all the credit. :)

Comment: @dmahapatro It's ok (=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't do anything important in you **catch** block. What will codenarc will say on this(move return to try block):

```
def finishBooking() {
    Booking booking = new Booking(params)
    try {
        booking = bookingService.saveBooking(booking)
        if (!booking.hasErrors()) {
            return [booking: booking]
        } else {
            flash.message = "Reservation failed. Check the required fields."
        }
    } catch (ReservationException e) {
        log.error("Error saving booking", e)
        flash.message = "Couldn't save the reservation."
    }
    render(view: "index", model: [booking: booking])
}
```

P.S. Thanks for the link. Never heard about codenarc.

Comment: Infact we have a plugin for [codenarc](http://grails.org/plugin/codenarc). It has been awesome yet. :)

Answer (score 2):

+1 @Mr. Cat. Something like.

```
def finishBooking() {
    Booking booking = new Booking(params)
    try {
        booking = bookingService.saveBooking(booking)
        if (booking.hasErrors()) {
            flash.message = "Reservation failed. Check the required fields."
            render(view: "index", model: [booking: booking])
        }
    } catch (ReservationException e) {
        log.error("Error saving booking", e)
        flash.message = "Couldn't save the reservation."
        render(view: "index", model: [booking: booking])
    }

    [booking: booking]
}
```